# Store class member and initializer value inside dedicated RAM section with Flash LOADADDR

Tags: c++, linker, stm32

I can store data in a "storage" section of my RAM that whose initializer values are loaded from the flash. This allows me to reprogram the associated flash load address to save the data easily.

This is my linker script modification

```
.storage_flash : 
  {
    __storage_flash_start__ = LOADADDR(.storage);  /* Start of storage in FLASH */
  } > STORAGE_FLASH

  .storage : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __storage_start__ = .;
    *(.storage*)
    __storage_end__ = .;
  } > STORAGE_RAM AT> STORAGE_FLASH
```

This simple code works - I can observe each value be incremented at each reset

```
#define STORAGE  __attribute__((section(".storage")))

extern uint64_t __storage_start__;
extern uint64_t __storage_end__;
extern uint64_t __storage_flash_start__;

uint8_t data1 STORAGE = 0x11;
uint8_t data2 STORAGE = 0x22;
uint8_t data3 STORAGE = 0x33;

void main(){
    data1++;
    data2++;
    data3++;
    memcpy(&__storage_start__, &__storage_flash_start__, &__storage_end__ - & __storage_start__); // Could be performed by the startup.s
    // I use HAL to copy the RAM section to the flash
}
```

I have a data wrapper class that pairs a raw value with some specific methods.
Operators are overloaded so the wrapper can be used just as the raw data

```
template <typename T> 
    class Wrapper {
    public :
        T value;
        Wrapper(T initializer) : value(initializer);
        // Operator overloading
        // Specific methods
    }

Wrapper<int> foo(0x88);
```

**Is there a way to specify that **value** should be stored in the storage section and not the whole object and to store the initializer to the corresponding flash address?**

I understand this would not be possible if these wrapper objects can be created at run-time but they cannot. (I never use **new Wrapper()**)
All pointers could be known at compile-time